# Flex spacing inside vbox, hbox

Tags: apache-flex, layout, containers

children inside hbox and vbox have spacing between them,

how do you remove this empty space?

I need to have 0 space between child elements of a hbox or vbox

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the verticalGap/horizontalGap properties to 0.

Comment: in a VGroup in spark, this is just the "gap" property

Answer (score 0):

You should probably still set the horizontalGap to 0, and than add paddingLeft and paddingRight to all the elements that need spacing...